# How do I make my xampp server public using my public ip address?

Tags: webserver, web-hosting

I have just installed xampp 1.7.7. I need to know what I need to do in order to make my website public using my public IP address (not 192.168.xxx.xxx) Also, I am behind a router (NETGEAR WPN824v3). I do have a dynamic IP address, but I have reserved the IP via my router. My operating system is Windows 7 Professional x64.

1. Do I need port forwarding? --> If so, what is the server IP (won't let me choose anything besides 192.168.xxx(cannot change).xxx(needs to be entered manually))? and what is the start port and end port?
2. What other changes do I need to make to make my website public without using:
   127.0.0.1, 192.168.xxx.xxx,localhost,etc....
3. How do I configure a domain name (from DOT TK)?

Please give me a step-by-step detailed list of instructions on how to do this and don't refer me to other websites please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Q: This sounds like a home network, correct?
2. Q: Do you have a registered domain?  Or do you want people to access your site by IP address?
3. Your internal, LAN address is 192.168.*.*.

   You can find your external ("WAN") address by looking at your router (which may be the Netgear, or might be yet another router - the one built in to your DSL or cable modem).

   You can also find it by pointing your browser here:

   - http://www.whatismyip.com
4. Be advised that, unless you have a "static IP" from your provider, this external address might change at any time.  It might stay the same for months ... or it might change multiple times/day.  "It depends".
5. Be advised, too, that the *moment* you open *anything* on your firewall - *especially* a web site - you leave yourself potentially vulnerable to hackers.  You absolutely need to make sure you have adequate security in place to protect against this eventuality.
6. Suggestion: look at DynDNS (or alternatives):

   - http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/

   Or just shop around for a web hosting service that appeals to you :)

Comment: 1. A: Yes
2. A: How do I register my domain(I don't want to use an ip address for my name)?
3. I know my external ip address.
4. I have reserved my current ip address so it should stay the same(should be static)
5. What would you recommend I use for security?
6. Goes back to #4.

NOTE: I did manage to get it working. The only problem is that I cannot access the "test" page. Instead, it leads me to my router config page. My friend can access the 'test' page, but I can't unless I use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I register my domain(I don't want to use an ip address for my
>   name)

http://www.no-ip.com/  (free)

Comment: I can get an account for free, but I cannot seem to get a actual domain registered for free. Same for DynDns.org.