# XAMPP Apache shows router page instead of Application

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

Pretty simple issue but cannot figure this out. I have a simple app in Windows 10 in the `xampp` folder. I have port forwarded using my router. However, when I put my public IP in the browser, I see the router's page instead of the App. The app works fine on the `localhost`. It is a `php` app. I have tried scores of changes to `httpd-conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` ..but it still doesn't work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app">  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
    </Directory>
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I am a little confused with this `##ServerName dummy-host.example.com` . I plan on accessing the app using just the IP Address, so I don't know what the `ServerName` should be. Is access to some folders blocked by anychance? Do I need to make changes in the `httpd-xampp.conf` file as well? A bit confusing this is. Some clarity is much appreciated.

P.S:- I don't want to map a domain. I am seeing the router's page..I want to see the index when accessing via the public IP..for now the public IP shows the router's page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my xampp server public using my public ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147430/how-do-i-make-my-xampp-server-public-using-my-public-ip-address)

Comment: @jrswgtr No, it doesn't. That guy is asking about domain mapping. I am simply using the IP..I wrote..I am seeing the router's page...I don't see that in the question...My question is about the configuration in Apache files..not setting a domain etc.

Comment: Hi ! Does it work if you try with the local ip of the server ? I can't remember the technical term, but with some routers (at least mine), in local access you must use the local ip with the real port, though from the outside it works fine (based on nat/pat rules).

Comment: The problem you have is not with Apache but your router configuration, if you get the router's default page, that means your port forwarding rule is not working, I would suggest you to change your local Apache to listen on port 8080, then open local firewall rules in your OS and then configure your router's port forwarding rules to send the traffic from your Public IP -> Back to your computer IP (lets say 192.168.1.55) on port 8080 (which you need to make sure apache is listening, including the Vhost), some times routers blocks common ports like 80,443,22 to avoid people hosting services.

Comment: @ReynaldoAceves There was actually no problem, anywhere. The issue was NAT hairpin. Simply means, I was checking the connectivity from inside the same network. When I accessed it from another network..it connected fine. The problem here was that the router did not correctly implement NAT Loopback, meaning a loop such as:
PC -> router -> internet -> router -> PC

Comment: @AbhishekRai That's what my question meant ;) `loopback` was the term I didn't remember ^^